# Need to forward custom port to port 80

Tags: networking, portforwarding

I am new in Windows Server 2016. Currently, I am using Windows Server 2016 on Amazon Web Server and I need to forward custom port to 80. The server will be running an aplication that need to be accessed via ip address. 
Example: When I open program, I can access it on browser "localhost:10000". But, I want to make possible for everyone to access it via ip address.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done via your router, login to your router via the "Default Gateway" and you should be able to find port forwarding option in the menu of your router, most modern routers have this added to their menu now a day.

And if you need a local server for the files to be hosted at you can use Xampp.

Guides on how to portforward can be easily found on google.

http://www.abyssunderground.co.uk/router-portforwarding.php
https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/

Answer (score 0):

Open up command prompt and type 'ipconfig'.
Copy the default gateway into your search bar, and find a port-forwarding menu or a 'NAT/QoS' menu.